# How To Submit Form Data to Spring Boot at Vuejs

Tags: forms, spring-boot, vue.js, submit

I want to ask submit form data at Vue to Spring Boot.

Is there any recommendation to do it?

I write down my project tree below.

---

.mvn

.vscode

frontend - Vue Project

src - Spring Boot src

target

.gitignore

...

---

In Register.vue file submit user data..

```
<template>
    <div id="register-app">
        <b-form @submit="onSubmit" id="register-form">
            <b-form-group 
                id="register-email"
                label="email"
                label-for="email"
            >
                <b-form-input type="email" id="email" placeholder="email"></b-form-input>
            </b-form-group>

            <b-form-group
                id="register-password"
                label="password"
                label-for="password"
            >
                <b-form-input type="password" id="password" placeholder="password"></b-form-input>
            </b-form-group>

            <b-form-group
                id="register-name"
                label="name"
                label-for="name"
            >
                <b-form-input type="text" id="name" placeholder="name"></b-form-input>
            </b-form-group>

            <b-form-group
                id="register-corporation"
                label="corporation"
                label-for="corporation"
            >
                <b-form-input type="text" id="corporation" placeholder="corporation"></b-form-input>
            </b-form-group>

            <b-form-group  id="register-button-group">
                <b-button type="submit" id="register" variant="primary">register</b-button>
                <b-button type="reset" id="reset" variant="danger">reset</b-button>
            </b-form-group>
        </b-form>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: This looks fine...are you getting any error while submitting?

Comment: No error here. I want to know submit data to spring boot @RestController. Is there any good example handle data to Controller?

Answer (score 0):

I have written a Vue 2 CLI application that connects to a Spring Boot REST API that I also wrote.  Here is a link to one of the .vue files that submits a form to the API.
[CustomerCreateOrEdit.vue](https://github.com/UniquelySimilar/vue-client-for-spring-rest/blob/master/src/views/customer/CustomerCreateOrEdit.vue)